# SqlException: do not abort a transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

I have a code that adds data to two EntityFramework 6 DataContexts, like this:

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(var requestsCtx = new RequestsContext())
    {
        using(var logsCtx = new LogsContext())
        {
            var req = new Request { Id = 1, Value = 2 };
            requestsCtx.Requests.Add(req);

            var log = new LogEntry { RequestId = 1, State = "OK" };
            logsCtx.Logs.Add(log);

            try
            {
                requestsCtx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.State = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }

            logsCtx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

There is an insert trigger in `Requests` table that rejects some values using `RAISEERROR`. This situation is normal and should be handled by the `try-catch` block where the `SaveChanges` method is invoked. If the second `SaveChanges` method fails, however, the changes to both DataContexts must be reverted entirely - hence the transaction scope.

Here goes the error: when `requestsCtx.SaveChanges()` throws a exception, the whole `Transaction.Current` has its state set to `Aborted` and the latter `logsCtx.SaveChanges()` fails with the following:

```
TransactionException:
The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
```

Why is this happening and how do tell EF that the first exception is not critical?

Comment: This is bad design. Only insert values that are valid. With the current design you are working against how the technologies are meant to be used.

Comment: @usr, but the validation itself is implemented in the trigger. This way I can write the rules once and be sure that no invalid data **ever** gets into the table, even when manually entering it from SQL Management Studio. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: @Impworks it sounds like you're kind of mixing concepts between different layers.  If your trigger is going to prevent a data insert, but still needs to be logged - log the data in the trigger itself - or replicate the trigger logic in your EF entities and complete the logging from there.  From the scenario you just described, you're worried about data inserts from management studio - but as it currently stands you would not get your logging for successes ***or*** failures if the insert was done via SSMS.

Comment: I'd endorse putting a safeguard in a trigger. I'd still (redundantly) validate in the application. It just works more naturally with the technologies we have... I'd consider the trigger firing a bug in every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally figured it out. The trick was to use an isolated transaction for the first `SaveChanges`:

```
using(var requestsCtx = new RequestsContext())
using(var logsCtx = new LogsContext())
{
    var req = new Request { Id = 1, Value = 2 };
    requestsCtx.Requests.Add(req);

    var log = new LogEntry { RequestId = 1, State = "OK" };
    logsCtx.Logs.Add(log);

    using(var outerScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using(var innerScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            try
            {
                requestsCtx.SaveChanges();
                innerScope.Complete();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.State = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }

        logsCtx.SaveChanges();
        outerScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Warning: most of the articles about `RequiresNew` mode discourage using it due to performance reasons. It works perfectly for my scenario, however if there are any side effects that I'm unaware of, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure if this will work, but it might be worth trying.

```
private void SaveChanges()
{
    using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var log = CreateRequest();
        bool saveLogSuccess = CreateLogEntry(log);

        if (saveLogSuccess)
        {
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}    

private LogEntry CreateRequest()
{
    var req = new Request { Id = 1, Value = 2 };
    var log = new LogEntry { RequestId = 1, State = "OK" };

    using(var requestsCtx = new RequestsContext())
    {
        requestsCtx.Requests.Add(req);

        try
        {
            requestsCtx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.State = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            return log;
        }
    }
}

private bool CreateLogEntry(LogEntry log)
{
    using(var logsCtx = new LogsContext())
    {
        try
        {
            logsCtx.Logs.Add(log);

            logsCtx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

from the documentation on transactionscope: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> If no exception occurs within the transaction scope (that is, between
>   the initialization of the TransactionScope object and the calling of
>   its Dispose method), then the transaction in which the scope
>   participates is allowed to proceed. If an exception does occur within
>   the transaction scope, the transaction in which it participates will
>   be rolled back.

Basically as soon as an exception is encountered, the transaction is rolled back (as it seems you're aware) - I think this *might* work but am really not sure and can't test to confirm.  It seems like this goes against the intended use of transaction scope, and I'm not familiar enough with exception handling/bubbling, but maybe it will help! :)

Comment: This way, if `logsCtx.SaveChanges()` happens to fail, changes to `requestsCtx` are not reverted. I mentioned this requirement in my question.

Comment: Updated - said it in the updates but worth mentioning here as well really have no idea if this would work.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work either. It is identical to my snippet in terms of exception/transaction nesting, because the exception in `CreateRequest` spoils the overall transaction.